# cannot save the results of find command in a file - file is empty

Tags: linux, shell

The program is supposed to find a file and return whether it exists on the system or not, now i have found that find command should be used, but since this command will be initiated by the code (using System) i need to save the results in a file, and trying on the terminal, i cannot get it to work, the result doesn't appear in the file, i am trying:

```
find / -name 'test2abc' 2>/dev/null -> res
```

The file res is empty. How to do it right?

Also is there a better way to do it, i am supposed to print the details of the file using stat command if the file exists. Is there a way to use juts the stat command to search for the file in the subfolders as well?

Comment: If you just want to stat the file, look at `find`'s `-exec` argument.

Comment: Why is there an offtopic close vote on this question?????????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-> res` part should be `> res` only.

If you try the command like this on the commandline:

```
find / -name 'test2abc' -> res
```

it will print an error:

```
find: paths must precede expression: -
```

The `-` is not part of any valid redirection and hence given to `find` which cannot interpret it either.

It may be wise not to suppress error messages. A simple way can be redirecting both stderr and stdout to the file like this:

```
find / -name 'test2abc' > res 2>&1
```

Then the error about the `-` would have been in the file right from the start you you would have known what`s wrong very fast.

Comment: It works fine, thanks a lot. But why -> res does not work in this case?

Comment: @SpeedBirdNine: `->` isn't how shell writes redirects, `>` is. So the `-` is being passed to find as an argument, which is producing an error (or would, were you not redirecting stderr to /dev/null)

Comment: @SpeedBirdNine I enhanced the post. OK?